# How To pass Variable as an String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to pass Var Variable value in Javascript function.I need to pass "name" in the field of "Raju" name must be passed as an string value.How i will do it.

My code is:

```
function setSelectedIndex(s, v) {
    for (var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].text == v) {
            s.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
var name = '@ViewData["CustName"]';
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('Cust_Id'), "Raju");
```

Comment: `eval()`. Haters gonna hate ;)

Comment: It's possible I've completely misunderstood, but seems like: `setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('Cust_Id'), name);` would be correct...

Comment: Are you using MVC and razor?  And @ViewData["CustName"] contains "Raju"?

Comment: In my Dropdown list i have lot of names i need to get lastly selected name from dropdown, In ViewData["CustName"] had that name In the Place OF RAJU i want to pass ViewData["CustName"]

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

But you can hash it like this:

```
var name = "Raju"     
var your_Var = { name: "Raju", value: whatever_you_wish}
```

than you can pass it like this

```
 setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('Cust_Id'), your_Var[name]);
```

Comment: pass Variable value in the field of "Raju" by '' + name + ''...

It is my old Code

> var name = '@ViewData["CustName"]';
> setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('Cust_Id'), "Raju");
It is my Solution Code,Now i got selected names in dropdownlist..

> var name = '@ViewData["CustName"]';
> setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('Cust_Id'), '' + name + '');

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
if (s.options[i].text == v.toString()) {
}
```

Comment: Solution pass Variable value in the field of "Raju" by '' + name + ''...

It is my old Code

> var name = '@ViewData["CustName"]';
> setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('Cust_Id'), "Raju");
It is my Solution Code,Now i got selected names in dropdownlist..

> var name = '@ViewData["CustName"]';
> setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('Cust_Id'), '' + name + '');

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass your `var` name.

```
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('Cust_Id'), name);
```

Comment: i need to pass name as like "+ name "

Comment: Solution pass Variable value in the field of "Raju" by '' + name + ''...

It is my old Code

> var name = '@ViewData["CustName"]';
> setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('Cust_Id'), "Raju");
It is my Solution Code,Now i got selected names in dropdownlist..

> var name = '@ViewData["CustName"]';
> setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('Cust_Id'), '' + name +'');

Answer (score 0):

I pass Variable value in the field of "Raju" by   '' + name + ''...

It is my old Code

```
> var name = '@ViewData["CustName"]';
> setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('Cust_Id'), "Raju");
```

It is my Solution Code,Now i got selected names in dropdownlist..

```
> var name = '@ViewData["CustName"]';
> setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('Cust_Id'), '' + name + '');
```